# Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead

Tags: next.js

So I have tried to debug this issue without any success. I am using Next.js and I am importing Link like this:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
```

I am using this thing only 3 times and I am using `href`. However, I am getting this error:

```
Call Stack
createPropError
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (59:19)
eval
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (69:26)
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
Link
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (66:22)
processChild
file:///home/david/website/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3353:14)
resolve
file:///home/david/website/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3270:5)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.render
file:///home/david/website/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3753:22)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.read
file:///home/david/website/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3690:29)
Object.renderToString
file:///home/david/website/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (4298:27)
Object.renderPage
file:///home/david/website/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (596:45)
```

Which doesn't tell me anything... I even commented out all of the places where I am using the Link component (just 3) and the problem persists, so I am sure that it's other problem I am having but getting this error message somehow.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: Are you dynamically passing value for the `href` attribute in `Link` ? if so, can you check its value once

Comment: @juliomalves I wish I could... But I am not sure how because I don't know where the error is coming from and I can't put all the files of my project.

Comment: @RGog no, all the `href` have a hardcoded string. And as I said, I commented them out and the error is still present.

Comment: @juliomalves So I have found the source of the issue. I was doing an import like this: `import Image from 'next/link'`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I was importing an image incorrectly: `import Image from 'next/link'`.

Comment: The correct import is `import Image from 'next/image'`